# Best Control to add Multiple UserControl in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view

I have a MainWindow in which i want to add my others Views.
Users can open Mutliple number of different Views to the MainWindow.

So for adding all those Views(UserControls), which is the best control to use.

Current I am using Canvas, but its not supporting MVVM.

So how can i add multiple control.

This is what i have done till now

[image]

Note:
The control should host multiple UserControl by the same time i should be able to drag One UserControl here and there in that control and then on a click on UserControl should bring it to Front(Focused), which i did in Canvas using ZIndex.

Comment: are this `views` esclusive? I mean, if I see one view, can I see also others?

Comment: ya, use should able to view all views in that control

Comment: A canvas seems like it should work. What do you mean that it doesn't support MVVM?

Comment: I am search for an better solution..

Comment: @KishoreJangid Nice window style, is there possible to get that style?

Comment: Is that a theme or have you designed it?

Comment: @mrid I had designed it.

Answer (score 1):

Proper MVVM solution migh be to use ItemsControl class and bind collection of view-models as an ItemsSource.

In DataTemplate of that ItemsControl, I would specify proper view for child view-models (sort of tool-window in your case).

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <views:ToolWindow DataContext={Binding} />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

To achieve window-like behavior as on your picture I would specify custom panel based on Canvas which would allow drag and drop behavior.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <panels:MyCustomMdiPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

I suppose that you have already working canvas solution.

Comment: thanks i am already using an cuaton draggable canvas. but my problem is i .not able to add childs from different viewmodels.